# GCP Data Fusion Error - Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I was following this GCP Data fusion tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/reusable-pipeline#set_the_macro_arguments), but I ran into this warning message and failed my pipeline. The warning message is below:

```
Error making GET request to url https://storage.cloud.google.com/reusable-pipeline-tutorial/args.json with headers {}: Could not parse response from 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/reusable-pipeline-tutorial/args.json': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

If you open the url in the error message, you can clearly see that the code starts with a curly bracket (i.e. {), rather than a string. Anyone has any idea how to resolve this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHZKO.jpg)
I know in that tutorial linked above, it says, at step 4, "In the URL field, enter the following.
gs://reusable-pipeline-tutorial/args.json" In my configuration, I put the https:// URL (rather than the gs:// URI since the URI won’t even pass the “validate” check). You can find my configuration in the picture.

Comment: Could you check the json file in gcs if it is in correct json format ?